# How to disable main window when popup is loaded?

Tags: angular, webforms

Application opens angular popup from the menu in web forms. When the pop-up window opens you can still click on the parent window, it is not protected with loading message.

```
<div class="iframeRoot">
            <iframe id="urIframe" name="urIframe" class="iframe" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let iframe = window.frames.urIframe;
        iframe.onload = function () {
            iframe.focus();
        }
    </script>

 urIframe.Attributes.Add(...
```

Comment: Render the iFrame with a `z-index: 9999` and a custom div with z-index:9998 and position absolute that's 100% width and 100vh height

Comment: you can still minimize window and click on parent window

Comment: You can't control minimize button.

Comment: I don't need to control button. I just want to show loading message on parent window.